# Socket.io syntax

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I got the following code from [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) docs:

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('event', function(data){});
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
});
server.listen(3000);
```

The syntax of the second line seems strange to me:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

All I understand is `require` is a function which gets `socket.io` as a parameter. But why that `server` comes at the end?

Comment: which means `require("socket.io")` returns a function.and if you execute the function with a parameter `server`,it will returns a object having functions for using websocket.(like `on` you are using)
So the code you put is a shorten version of the code below.
`var Io = require("socket.io");` `var io = Io(server);`

Answer (score 0):

A `require()` function call returns the `module.exports` object from the module.  That object can be a "constructor function" (functions are objects) which is designed to be called in order to initialize the module.  That is the case here and the reason it is done that way is because an argument (the server object) is required for the module to initialize itself.

Your code:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

can be thought of a little more simply as this:

```
// get the socket.io module
var io_module = require('socket.io');

// call the socket.io constructor to initialize a socket.io instance that
// is hooked up to a particular server
var io_instance = io_module(server);
```

So, your single line of code is really just a shortcut for this two step process that doesn't retain a handle to the module itself.

---

Internally in the socket.io module, it would look like this:

```
module.exports = function(server) {
    // called to initialize the module

    // create a socket.io instance and return it
    // ...

    return instance;
}
```